# Arduino Due output TIOA and TIOB without interrupts

Tags: arduino

I am an electrical student and want to use arduino due to generate pulses for driving  MOSFETs. I am making a  inverter and want to generate pulses. I  have arduino due with me. My main aims are :

1) one software interrupt for sampling the next time period (this will be changing..). After three cycles I will analogRead() new value of time period  and same continues .

2)  During one time period,set by RC count of Timer channel TC0, I want to load RA0 and RB0 with appropriate counts to get output pulses with different duty ratios(depending on RA0 and RB0 values).

I wrote a program which gives software interrupts with TC3 which is working fine. i.e. I am able to load new values into RA0 and RB0 automatically for every new sampled value( every 3 cycles new values comes else same values will be loaded).
Now I also used TC0 (i used Olavi Kamppari's library) for stopping, loading new values and starting the timer.
when i checked PIO_PB25B_TIOA0 and PIO_PB27B_TIOB0 in the serial monitor i am getting 33554432,134217728 .

I am really confused.I expected a 1 and 0 output. I just want two pulses from TC0 without interrupt.I set the ACPA value to 3 (Toggle) and I enabled the clock to the timer as well.Still I am not getting the output.

**So if possible please provide me a sample program that can output pulses from PB25 and PB27 (TIOA0 and TIOB0).** Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for reading my question.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The following sketch outputs a 3 MHz signal on `TIOA6` (Pin 5 from memory)

I am about to post a question regarding the same code - I want to get to 8 (and a little bit) MHz but have hit a conceptual brick wall!

Note that this is under development - the IRQ handler is not used - and the `PMC_Enable_Periph` should be referring to `ID_TC6` (I believe) - then the IRQ handler can be placed in the dust bin of history!

```
void TC6_Handler()
{
        TC_GetStatus(TC2, 0);    
}

void startTimer(Tc *tc, uint32_t channel, IRQn_Type irq) {
        pmc_set_writeprotect(false);
        pmc_enable_periph_clk((uint32_t)irq);

        TC_Configure(tc, channel,
               TC_CMR_WAVE |
               TC_CMR_WAVSEL_UP_RC |
               TC_CMR_TCCLKS_TIMER_CLOCK1|
               TC_CMR_ACPA_TOGGLE );  // RC compare TOGGLES TIOA)smiley-wink;

        TC_SetRA(tc, channel, 1); //50% high, 50% low
        TC_SetRC(tc, channel, 1);


         PIO_Configure(PIOC,
                       PIO_PERIPH_B,
                       PIO_PC25B_TIOA6,
                       PIO_DEFAULT);

         TC_Start(tc, channel);     
}

void setup(){    
        startTimer(TC2, 0, TC6_IRQn);
}

void loop(){
}
```

Comment: By the way, I suspect you and I hit the same problem - not getting anything out on the pin - the PIO_Configure is the thing that enables the output - look in the due varient.h and varient.cpp for some hints as to what you configure (I am pretty sure from memory Varient.cpp has a table (The structure is defined in varient.h) that describes the pins - substitute accordingly).

Comment: Thanks for the response..but i have solved the problem way back and also completed my project. I wrote a new library for simplifying my project code using timer libraries. Thank you.